# How can I access to my Grid table from my private method

Tags: c#, wpf, button, grid

I started yesterday a new proyect in c# with WPF. My first time with it.

I'm trying to do the tictactoe game with graphical interface so i create the grid and i use bottons to change the state (it's not finish yet).

Here is the declaration of the class:

```
    public partial class juego : Window
    {
        private juego tab;
        public juego( int size)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.tab = CreateDynamicWPFGrid(size);
         }
```

Here is the method that created the grid.

```
    public juego CreateDynamicWPFGrid(int size)
    {
        Grid DynamicGrid = new Grid();
        DynamicGrid.Name = "GridTablero";
        DynamicGrid.Width = 400;
        DynamicGrid.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
        DynamicGrid.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
        DynamicGrid.ShowGridLines = true;
        DynamicGrid.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightSteelBlue);
       for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            ColumnDefinition gridCol1 = new ColumnDefinition();
            DynamicGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(gridCol1);
            RowDefinition gridRow1 = new RowDefinition();
            gridRow1.Height = new GridLength(45);
            DynamicGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(gridRow1);
        }
        for (int fila = 0; fila < DynamicGrid.RowDefinitions.Count; fila++)
        {
            for (int columna = 0; columna < DynamicGrid.RowDefinitions.Count; columna++)
            {
                System.Windows.Controls.Button newBtn = new Button();
                newBtn.Content = fila.ToString() + "_" + columna.ToString();
                newBtn.Name = "Button" + fila.ToString() + "_" + columna.ToString();
                newBtn.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, columna);
                newBtn.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, fila);
                newBtn.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(button_Click);
                DynamicGrid.Children.Add(newBtn);
            }

        }
        tablero.Content = DynamicGrid;
        return tablero;
    }
```

So the thing is that i want to iterate over the grid and then, count the buttons which content means if they are X, O or white.

I tried to use in my private method something like tab.Content but i really don't have any idea.
Anyways, i would like to know if this it is even possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all, i come up with a solution by myselft.

So, i changed some lines in the class.

```
public partial class juego : Window
{
    private ArrayList jugadores;

    public juego(ArrayList jugadores, int size)
    {
        InitializeComponent();



        tablero.Content = CreateDynamicWPFGrid(size);

}
```

Then i changed the return from the CreateDynamicWPFGrid:

```
return dynamicGrid;
```

And then, one method that i call when i click on buttons.

```
        Grid boardValidar = tablero.Content as Grid;


        Button[,] botones = new Button[boardValidar.ColumnDefinitions.Count, boardValidar.ColumnDefinitions.Count];

        var buttons = boardValidar.Children.Cast<Button>();

        for (int i = 0; i < boardValidar.ColumnDefinitions.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < boardValidar.RowDefinitions.Count; j++)
            {
                botones[i, j] = buttons.Where(x => Grid.GetRow(x) == j && Grid.GetColumn(x) == i).FirstOrDefault();

            }
        }
```

So, i cast the grid and then, i do the same with all the buttons.
After this i use the linq to put in the array and that's all.
I know my code it's no the best but i got what i wanted.